# php form with two dates validation (before submit)

Tags: php, forms, validation, date

I'm trying to create a validation for an "", but I can't understand how to.

The form has two dates:

1. DateStart
2. Datestop (must be after Datestart).

These variables are stored as associative array (routine['col'] =>'val').
I created this:

```
<form ..>
 ...
 <tr>
     <td>Star date: </td>
     <td><input type="date" name="routine[Datestart]"></td>
 </tr><?php $routine['Datestart']; ?>
 <tr>
     <td>Stop Date: </td>
     <td><input type="date" name="routine[Datestop]"
         min="routine[Datestart]"></td>
 </tr>
 ...
</form>
```

Obviously, the **min option** doesn't work.

I saw that some solution are provided by Javascripts, but I never used Java, so if I could do it with a simple php variable it would be better, but I'm looking for the smartest solution, so I ask to you simply how to do that.

Comment: Javascript and Java are completely different things. Javascript just has a really stupid name because Java was the cool new thing back in the day.

Comment: You cannot perform any PHP validation prior to submitting the form. The ONLY way to perform validation BEFORE submitting the form is with Javascript. jQuery will make your life easy here ;)
https://jquery.com/

Comment: If you want the user to be told to fix an invalid date when they are entering the date in the browser Javascript is the only way. Of course you will also have to do this validation in PHP when the page is submitted as of course it is possible to turn off javascript or fake a submission without ever being near your actual page

Comment: The `min` attribute has to be a valid date. It does not support references to other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Validitions on the web are done in two places:

**On the server (PHP).** You always need to check user input on your server before inserting data from the wild webs into your database. The simplest possible validation to check that a field is not blank would be:

```
<?php

$errors = array();

if ( empty($POST["foo"]) || count($POST["foo"]) < 1) {
  $errors["foo"] = "Foo can't be blank";
}

if ( empty($errors) ) {
  // all good here
} else {
  // display errors to user.
}
```

This is a pretty trivial example and great volumes have been written on different ways to validate user input.

To compare two dates in PHP you need to parse the input string into a two DateTime objects which you then can compare:

```
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::RFC3339, $routine['Datestart']);
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::RFC3339, $routine['Dateend']);

if ($start > $end) {
  // its not valid.
}
```

**In the browser**. Since server side validions require the user to press send before getting feedback which is pretty slow at times they are often complemented with client side validations which give instant feedback while the user types. The are written in Javascript [not to be confused with Java] since it is the universal language of the browser.

However they are never a replacement for client side validations as a script error or the user not having javascript enabled would disable the validations.

Answer (score 0):

you should use jquery like this.

jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("#DateFrom").datepicker(
                    {
                        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        yearRange: '-50:+50',
                        maxDate: 'today',
                        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                            $("#DateTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                        }
                    }
            );

            $("#DateTo").datepicker(
                    {
                        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        yearRange: '-50:+50',
                        maxDate: 'today',
                        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                            $("#DateFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                        }
                    }
            );

        });
    </script>
```

HTHML CODE OR JUST INCLUDE IT IN UR FORM

```
<center>
        <input type="text" id="DateFrom"> To
        <input type="text" id="DateTo">
    </center>
```

you have to include jquery datepicker js and css. files.

try this one it will works.